# Is it possible to show " New Task" of Task Manager from tasks of Task Manager only?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, administration

I work on remote Windows Server 2008 machine over RDP and frequently need to revive broken copy&pasting  over RDP.  Which is killing rdpclip process in Task Manger (tab "Processes")  and launching it gain by: switching to tab Applications --> pressing button "New Task..." --> typing 'rdpclip'--> clicking OK.

Well, I do not need to type 'rdpclip' if it is the last used command. The problem that in "Create New Task" of Windows Task Manager I always launch rdpclip only but it shows the last run program from Windows command prompt (Win +R), usually it is "notepad" for me.

[image]

Is it possible to bind the last used command/task to Task Manager only? 
and how?

Comment: Why do all this, why not just put a shortcut somewhere for rdpclip set to run as admin?

Comment: It is even more unconvenient. Before launching rdpclip I should deleted the ild process, so I am anywat alread in Task Manager. There is no much sense to go outside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best approach would be to create a batch file like this:

```
taskkill /im rdpclip.exe
rdpclip.exe
```

Put this somewhere convenient, and set it to run as administrator.

Then just run the batch file whenever you need to restart rdpclip.

Comment: @Synetech my commented suggestion was just to start rdpclip from a shortcut, whereas this both kills and restarts the process.  It addresses the issue without dealing with the XY nature of the question.